Laravel, awaiting response when try to access from VPN connection
Good morning, I have a problem with a Laravel v.10 platform.
Installed as a VMWare virtual machine on Debian 11 with nginx.
If I access from the local network everything works fine.
However, if I try to access via VPN, the request remains in "waiting" until I get a timeout error. I ping the server correctly.
If I try to replace the index.php (in the public folder) with a "echo", it works fine.
If I try to put an "phpinfo()", I still have a "waiting".
It seems that Laravel or php intervenes in the request processing, but I don't understand where and how.
You can help me?
Thank you

I'm still testing the issue and I can view the page (empty, but I can skip the "waiting" problem) if I remove this line from nginx/php configuration:
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

the problem was related to MTU of the WAN connection, lowering it to 1000 everything works correctly.
Thanks

I spent days debugging this exact issue, and this was the fix.  THANK YOU!!!!
You can use ping to test which MTU works: https://www.sonassi.com/help/troubleshooting/setting-correct-mtu-for-openvpn
